# Search Twitter for string that ends with a hyphen

Tags: twitter, search, tweet, tweetdeck

I'm trying to search Twitter and TweetDeck for tweets containing the string `mw17-`, but both web apps only show results without the hyphen (i.e. `mw17`).

I've tried wrapping my query in quotes `"mw17-"` and escaping the hyphen `mw17\-` with no luck.

Is there some way to search for a string ending in a hyphen on Twitter?

Comment: For me it is showing both `mw17` and `mw17-`, when I do simple search of `mw17-`.

Comment: @serenesat The goal is to show only `mw17-`.